# curl issue sending post to an external page

Tags: php, post, curl

Hi i need to send an external request to an another page (on an external website).
The code that i'using it's :

```
    $this->_prepare();


    $ch = curl_init($this->get_url());

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->get_url());    //request url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT         5.1; pl; rv:1.9) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->get_post_request_array());//post data elements

    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
```

When i send this request the external page will open into my website example :

`www.mywebsite.com/payment` and here i see the corrupt external page.

For solve this issue i need to open the page into a new window or into  the same window but with the external page url

how can i solve this? i know that i cant open a new window with curl but can i totally redirect to the new page without my url?

thanks and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to implement that in JavaScript. Curl is executed on server side, with JavaScript you can open new windows with custom URLs on client side.